# how to get a list of all tokens from Solr/Lucene index?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am wondering is there a way to get all tokens from particular record in Lucene/Solr index?

Thank you.

Comment: That's *exactly the opposite* of how Lucene works. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: yes, I am sure. I want to collects all tokens from text and I know that Lucene/Solr are best in this task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IndexReader.terms()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html) to get an enumeration of all terms that occur in the inverted index. This method returns a [TermEnum.](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/TermEnum.html)

Comment: thank you Athena, I found another solution. I use solr's filters directly to get tokens...

Comment: @cherven can you please share any link where you find the solution?

Comment: @Cherven yes, please share your solution. I also know no simple way to get tokens from SOLR. (wow, 7 years have passed)