# How to get a list of all tokens from Lucene 8.6.1 index?

Tags: java, python, search, lucene, pylucene

I have looked at [how to get a list of all tokens from Solr/Lucene index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356037/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-tokens-from-solr-lucene-index) but Lucene 8.6.1 doesn't seem to offer `IndexReader.terms()`. Has it been moved or replaced? Is there an easier way than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371411/apache-lucene-8-4-1-how-to-get-indexed-fields-and-term-list)?

Comment: here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371411/apache-lucene-8-4-1-how-to-get-indexed-fields-and-term-list) with some code in one answer extracting fields and terms. Basically iterate over all documents and `getValues` for each of thenm

Comment: Thanks @NikolaiDmitriev I guess that's one way but I'm just wondering if ```IndexReader.terms()``` has moved or been replaced by an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some History**

You asked: *I'm just wondering if `IndexReader.terms()` has moved or been replaced by an alternative.*

The Lucene v3 method [`IndexReader.terms()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#terms()) was moved to [`AtomicReader`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html) in Lucene v4. This was documented in the [v4 alpha release notes](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/changes/Changes.html#v4.0.0-alpha.changes_in_backwards_compatibility_policy).

(Bear in mind that Lucene v4 was released way back in 2012.)

The method in `AtomicReader` in v4 takes a [field name](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html#terms(java.lang.String)).

As the v4 release notes state:

> *One big difference is that field and terms are now enumerated separately: a TermsEnum provides a BytesRef (wraps a byte[]) per term within a single field, not a Term.*

The key part there is *"per term within a single field"*. So from that point onward there was no longer a single API call to retrieve all terms from an index.

This approach has carried through to later releases - except that  the `AtomicReader` and `AtomicReaderContext` classes were renamed to `LeafReader` and `LeafReaderContext` in Lucene v 5.0.0. See [Lucene-5569](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5569).

**Recent Releases**

That leaves us with the ability to access lists of terms - but only on a per-field basis:

The following code is based on the latest release of Lucene (8.7.0), but should also hold true for the version you mention (8.6.1) - with the example using Java:

```java
private void getTokensForField(IndexReader reader, String fieldName) throws IOException {
    List<LeafReaderContext> list = reader.leaves();

    for (LeafReaderContext lrc : list) {
        Terms terms = lrc.reader().terms(fieldName);
        if (terms != null) {
            TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();

            BytesRef term;
            while ((term = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
                System.out.println(term.utf8ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above example assumes an index as follows:

```java
private static final String INDEX_PATH = "/path/to/index/directory";
...
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_PATH)));
```

If you need to enumerate field names, the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128466/extracting-all-fields-from-a-lucene8-index) may provide a starting point.

**Final Note**

I guess you can also access terms on a *per document* basis, instead of a *per field* basis, as mentioned in the comments. I have not tried this.

Comment: sorry, I hadn't tested this out before accepting the answer. I'm trying this in Python and I get an error like this ```AttributeError: 'TermsEnum' object has no attribute 'next'```. I think its got something to do with "The TermsEnum is unpositioned when you first obtain it and you must first successfully call BytesRefIterator.next() or one of the seek methods." but I don't understand it. Could you please help?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used the Python wrapper for Lucene. Does `__next__()` exist? Or can you use `next(x)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073396/is-generator-next-visible-in-python-3)). Otherwise, I think you may need to ask a new Python question specifically about this.

Comment: Both ```next()``` and ```__next__()``` don't seem to work either. I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960527/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-tokens-from-lucene-8-6-1-index-using-pylucene).